Windows 10 - Block File Transfer
I would like to disable file transfer via Bluetooth while allowing other Bluetooth services to function normally such as mouse, keyboard, audio, etc.
The devices are not on a domain and are not connected to internet nor a network.
I have searched a lot and found a few solutions but none seems to do what I need.
For example disabling BTHPORT or Fsquirt in registry under Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\BTHPORT Parameter  by creating a key DisableFsquirt and set value under to 1 does not work.
Although the Fsquirt one hides send and receive options in taskbar Bluetooth icon but you can still access it in setting under Bluetooth section. See picture below.
Any help, suggestion, idea is welcomed and much appreciated.


Welcome to the community. Have you tried blacklisting the virtual device used for this kind of file transfers? Or at least researched this possibility?

While your intention might be security related, nothing in the question actually seems related to security.
